# Auto Posting on User wall with Feed

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook Feed for posting on user's wall without  showing feed dialog, its posting on the wall of loggedin user as per expected.
But In case if user has not authorized the app, it is not posting on wall, I want to show Dialog prompting to authenticate if user has not authenticated the app, I am using FB.getLoginStatus(), but its returning connected status, and from documentation I have read FB.getLoginStatus will return connected if,see [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/)

```
the user is logged into Facebook and has authenticated your application
```

This is how I am using FB.getLoginStatus()

```
 FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                        if (response.status === 'connected') {
                            alert("connt");
                            // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
                            // app, and response.authResponse supplies
                            // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
                            // request, and the time the access token 
                            // and signed request each expire
                            var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                            alert("not");
                            // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
                            // but has not authenticated your app
                        } else {
                            alert("aa");
                            // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
                        }
                    });
```

and this is my code for wall posting

```
 FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { link: mywebsitelink, picture: mypicture, message: message }, function (response) {
                        if (!response || response.error) {
                            alert(response.error.message);
                        } else {
                            //  alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
                        }
                    });
```

its showing error message,even FB.getLoginStatus showing connected.

```
(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action
```

Comment: “Connected” only means that the user has, well, connected to your app – but is says nothing about the permissions they might have given (apart from the basic ones that connecting implies). You’re aware that you need `publish_actions` permission to post to the user’s wall, right? So have you asked for that before …?

Answer (score 1):

The user needs to accept extended permissions () before being able to post on wall. Remember to include the "publish_stream" permission in the scope, when user accepts the app.

```
FB.login(function(response) {
// do you thing
}, {scope: 'publish_stream'});
```

FB.getLoginStatus() only tells you if app has be accepted, not if any of the extended permissions has been accepted too.